# sshd and Kerberos - getent passwd

Tags: ssh, kerberos

When [setting up sshd with Kerberos on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kerberos), one needs to "make sure that each each user has a valid account, either on the local host (via adduser or similar), or through a shared source such as LDAP

Why is that?

I can see if you use the GSSAPIAuthentication option or KerberosAuthentication, you've validated the user against a KDC.

Is this simply a matter of needing to  map the username to a userid?

Answer (score 1):

> > I can see if you use the GSSAPIAuthentication option or KerberosAuthentication, you've validated the user against a KDC

KDC validates the `principal`, not user account. (a principal can be created for a user, service etc.. for KDC, it's all principals and it verifies the identify of the same).

Linux require a username and it's corresponding `uid` & `gid` (and few optional attributes) to consider it as a valid user account. KDC has no idea/can't provide these details, hence the user details must be made available to OS via NSS. Depending on the configuration, it can fetch the user details from `files` [local user], `ldap` or some other source.

Once OS know it's a valid user account(`getent passwd user_name`), then you may use any available authentication mechanism (local passwd, ldap auth, kerberos etc..) to validate the user account.

For kerberos auth:  the system maps the principal (`abc@REALM`) to user `'abc'` by stripping the `REALM` portion(by default) and grants access if kerberos validation is successful for principal `abc@REALM`.

Answer (score 0):

Kerberos authentication tokens do not give security context, such as group permissions, which ldap provides, only if the credential was valid

Comment: Thanks - can you expand on 'tokens do not give security context' a bit? Why would I need group perms to login to a box that does not care about groups?

Comment: You care about groups, just one group being a domain use. Authentication tokens without context have no properties or purpose

Comment: Personally, I don't care per se. I am seeking to find out why the server cares. You spoke  much about groups. I don't see a connection to login and groups, especially if there are no restrictions at login for groups. One reason I see is being able to map the username to an id for the sake of allowing/denying permissions to file.